# fzf: How to return "ID" / line numbers?

Tags: command-line, fzf

I have a set of lines (item + description) which I want to run through `fzf -m`. For example:

```
item1: Some description
item1: Another description
item2: Yet another description
```

After selection I would like fzf to return the line numbers (e.g. `1 3`) instead of the lines themselves because: 1) I don't want to include the description; 2) The items are not unique.

True, I can just prefix the lines with the line numbers first:

```
1: item1: Some description
2: item1: Another description
3: item2: Yet another description
```

then extract it later. But I think it would be great if fzf can be instructed to do this. It will make some things easier and open some more possibilities for the tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fzf` can already do this with `--with-nth` to change the presented (and searched-for) line to only some fields of the original line. So we start with:

```
1: item1: Some description
2: item1: Another description
3: item2: Yet another description
```

then use:

```
fzf -d: --with-nth 2..
```

which means to skip showing the first field (the fields are separated by colon). fzf will then return something like this:

```
1: item1: Some description
3: item2: Yet another description
```

from which you can extract the line numbers.